# mod_rewrite trouble - RewriteEngine On gives 403 when trying to access subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got a webshop(xtCommerce) running on a shared hosting webspace.

The root directory (where shop 1 is installed, up and running) contains the .htaccess file provided by the shop software

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/extAdmin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/skin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php
```

I now installed a second webshop (also xtcommerce), within the same webspace, at /shop2 which contains the same .htaccess file

```
www.shop1.net -> /
www.shop2.net -> /shop2
```

-Trying to access shop2 results in 403
-When I'm removing RewriteEngine on from the .htaccess in /shop2 the frontpage displays just fine, but the links seem to be broken.

I don't know much about mod_rewrite, I tried adding RewriteBase /shop2 to the 2nd .htaccess file, but it failed.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Even when I use `RewriteRule .* http://google.de` in the root directory, and remove the .htaccess in /shop2 I keep getting "Forbidden". Maybe the problem isn't the rewriting?

**EDIT2: Current status:**
*.htaccess in /*

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/extAdmin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/skin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !shop2\.net$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php
```

*.htaccess in /shop2* (4 different examples)

```
RewriteRule .* index.php # frontpage shop2.net works, any URLs to be rewritten result in 404
RewriteRule .* shop2/index.php # frontpage shop2.net works, any URLs to be rewritten result in 404
RewriteRule .* http://google.de # frontpage shop2.net works, any URLs to be rewritten result in 404
#RewriteRule .* index.php # shop2.net => forbidden
```

Comment: Hard to say without testing, but you did right adding `RewriteBase /shop2`. Try again and also modify the rewrite rule like this: `RewriteRule .* shop2/index.php`.

Comment: I'm having the same issues after this modifications, the frontpage displays just fine, but the links (which point to URLs like www.shop2.net/de/Anything are resulting in "not found"

Answer (score 0):

Rather strange setup of virtual host you have there. The problem is the htaccess in the root is executed before the one in /shop2. The root htaccess rewrites the the index.php file in the root. But because the document_root for shop2.net is /shop2, it is the index.php file is outside of the document_root, so apache forbids this (as it should).
To fix this put this in the root htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !shop2.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/extAdmin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/skin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php
```

But better just create a separate folder for shop2, instead of a sub-folder of shop1